# How to load bootstrap-vue into Laravel 5 with laravel-mix?

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, laravel-mix, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to load [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) into a Laravel 5.6 project

The [official docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs) say to modify your **webpack.config.js** file like:

```
+   module: {
+     rules: [
+       {
+         test: /\.css$/,
+         use: [
+           'style-loader',
+           'css-loader'
+         ]
+       }
+     ]
+   }
```

Webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css

I don't have a webpack.config.js file so I tried loading the CSS in with Laravel mix

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles('node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css', 'public/css');
```

This give me an error

> **mix.combine() requires a full output file path as the second argument.**

and I'm not convinced it's the right way to do it.

What is the proper way to add bootstrap-vue into a new Laravel 5.6 project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Import the Bootstrap Vue styles in your `app.scss` file directly, instead of through mix:

```
// app.scss
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
@import "~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";

// webpack.mix.js
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

Laravel Mix already has the CSS loader configured so you don't need to set up a separate `webpack.config.js` file.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you